# Subset from a list of data.frames

Tags: r

I have a list of data.frames. Suppose the list is composed by 10 data.frames. I would like first of all rename each list of data.frames according to a list of names stored in another file. 
Second, suppose the data.frames is named "Pippo" and "Pippo" is an element of the data.frame. I would like to subset in the following way:

Suppose this is the data.frame named "Pippo" from the list of data.frames:

> ```
> Name   Sample1   Sample2  Sample3  Sample4
> John      1         0       -3       -7     
> Michael   0         4        2       21    
> Pippo     1         1        23      0
> ```

I would like to subset all the elements according to "Pippo" value == 1 so that the output will be:

> ```
> Name   Sample1   Sample2  
> John      1         0       
> Michael   0         4       
> Pippo     1         1
> ```

This will be done for all the names of the list of data.frames since each name is an element of the data.frame.

Comment: Just to clarify: are `John`, `Michael`, `Pippo` your data.frame's rownames or are they a column in your data.frame? My answer assumed the former.

Comment: hi flodel! They are column in data.frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `ldf` be your list of dataframes. You can change the list's names using:

```
names(ldf) <- v
```

where `v` is a character vector.

For the second step (subsetting), this should work:

```
subset.ldf <- mapply(ldf, names(ldf),
                     function(x, name) x[, x[name, ] == 1, drop = FALSE])
```

Answer (score 2):

Or a vector based solution:

```
d = data.frame(name=c('john','michael','pippo'), sample1 = c(1,0,1),
           sample2 = c(0,4,1), sample3 = c(-3,2,23), sample4 = c(-7,21,0))

sel = d[d$name == 'pippo',2:5]; sel = c(TRUE, sel == 1)
d[,sel]
```